# JAVA GUI, Want to make separate panel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, jpanel

I want to make a separate panel where there is a JTextField and where the function is drawn.
So I don't want each other to overlap.
How should I change the source code to make it like this?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class MyPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
JTextField a, b, c;
double A, B, C;

public MyPanel() {
    a = new JTextField("1.0", 10);
    b = new JTextField("-5.0", 10);
    c = new JTextField("6.0", 10);
    add(a);
    add(b);
    add(c);
    JButton button = new JButton("DRAW");
    add(button);
    button.addActionListener(this);
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.drawLine(0, 200, 400, 200);
    g2.drawLine(200, 0, 200, 400);
    g2.setPaint(Color.red);
    for (int i = -20; i<20; i++) {
        int x = i;
        int y = (int) (A * x * x - B * x + C);
        g2.fillOval(200+x-2, 200-(y-2), 4, 4);
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    A = Double.parseDouble(a.getText());
    B = Double.parseDouble(b.getText());
    C = Double.parseDouble(c.getText());
    repaint();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(new MyPanel());       
    f.setSize(500, 400);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do the drawing on your "MyPanel" class.

Instead your "MyPanel" class will just be a container for two child panels. You will need:

1. a JPanel for the text fields
2. an inner "DrawingPanel" to do the cuustom painting.

So the constructor code would be something like:

```
setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

JPanel top = new JPanel();
top.add(textField1);
...
add(top, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

add(new DrawingPanel(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Then the inner class for you DrawingPanel would be something like:

```
class DrawingPanel()
{
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
         return new Dimension(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you:)
But what code should I write in Dimension(...)??